# Creating piecewise anonymous function matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an expression that I want to be 0 if the sum of the two variables is even, and a function if the sum is odd.  I tried this:

```
fmn = @(m,n) (mod(m+n,2)~=0)*16*m*n/(pi^2*(m^2-n^2)^2);
```

My issue is that if I do this for m=n, then I get NaN instead of 0.  How can I resolve this to give 0 foro something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `1/(m^2-n^2)` is generating the `NaN` which is corrupting your function.  To get around this, you can add a small finiteness to the denominator (i.e., machine epsilon):

```
fmn = @(m,n) (mod(m+n,2)~=0)*16*m*n/(pi^2*((m^2-n^2)^2 + eps()));
```

or have a term that is only non-zero when `m` and `n` are sufficiently close:

```
fmn = @(m,n) (mod(m+n,2)~=0)*16*m*n/(pi^2*((m^2-n^2)^2 + abs(m-n)<=eps(m)));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didnt even think to do that